# Insert item in list after two elements

Tags: elixir, list-comprehension

I have the list

```
[%{A: %{}}, %{B: %{}}, %{C: %{}}]
```

how could I add `%{D: %{}}` between `B` and `C` based not in the index, like this:

```
[%{A: %{}}, %{B: %{}}, %{D: %{}}, %{C: %{}}]
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on how you're looking to insert those? Are you trying to say "put D in at index 2"?

Comment: I changed... i need to insert after A and B

Comment: `(fn [a, b | rest], c -> [a, b, c | rest] end).([%{A: %{}}, %{B: %{}}, %{C: %{
}}], %{D: %{}})`

Comment: When posting questions, please, make sure you have provided an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the first place. The noise does not make people who spend their spare time trying to help you happy. Here the MCVE would be: `[:a, :b, :c]`. All these maps just make it hard to understand the issue.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip [`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#with/1)? `with [a, b | rest] <- [:a, :b, :c], do: [a, b, :d | rest]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  def insert_between(a, b, list, x), do: insert_between(a, b, list, x, [])

  def insert_between(a, b, [a,b|tail], x, acc) do
    insert_between(a, b, tail, x, [b, x, a | acc])
  end
  def insert_between(a, b, [head|tail], x, acc) do
    insert_between(a, b, tail, x, [head|acc])
  end
  def insert_between(_, _ ,[], _, acc) do
    Enum.reverse(acc)
  end
```

Comment: This is just a less efficient version of my answer. Why always go through the entire list when you can stop if you find the match? And to top it off, you then need to reverse the list in your answer, which means you are actually going through the list fully twice.

Comment: That is just not true. https://gist.github.com/ankhers/290f58253dcc0e6237b40a888b047cb6. If it was as efficient as you said, it would not take ~2 seconds to reverse a list of `100_000_000` size. And even if it were as efficient, you are still iterating through the entire list unnecessarily after finding the match. You are also matching `[head|tail]` and recreating the list as `[head|tail]`. I'm not sure if there is an optimization for that, but it would be more idiomatic to write `[_ | _] = list`.

Answer (score 1):

`List.insert_at/3` would seem conventional. If you can't use the index, how about using pattern matching?

```
iex> [a, b, c] = [%{A: %{}}, %{B: %{}}, %{C: %{}}]
[%{A: %{}}, %{B: %{}}, %{C: %{}}]
iex> d = %{D: %{}}
%{D: %{}}
iex> [a, b, d, c]
[%{A: %{}}, %{B: %{}}, %{D: %{}}, %{C: %{}}]
```

I guess this answer assumes you know the position where you want to insert the item. But it doesn't use that information in a function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to insert some value between two maps with specific keys, and not based on the index. If so, you would need to use recursion. Something like the following should give you what you are looking for.

```
def insert_between(value, [a, b | rest], key1, key2) do
  if Map.has_key?(a, key1) and Map.has_key?(b, key2) do
    [a, value, b | rest]
  else
    [a | insert_between(value, [b | rest], key1, key2)]
  end
end
# This is the catch all for the scenario where key1 and key2 are not found
# directly next to each other.
def insert_between(_value, list, _key1, _key2) do
  list
end

iex(2)> insert_between(%{d: :d}, [%{a: :a}, %{b: :b}, %{c: :c}], :b, :c)
[%{a: :a}, %{b: :b}, %{d: :d}, %{c: :c}]
```

I have no idea what you want to do when you cannot find the keys to be direct neighbours of each other, so my version does nothing in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged [list-comprehension](/questions/tagged/list-comprehension), here is the answer with [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) list comprehension.

```
input = ~w|a b c|a

for e <- input, reduce: [] do
  acc -> if e == :b, do: [:d, :b | acc], else: [e | acc]
end |> :lists.reverse()
#⇒ [:a, :b, :d, :c]
```

---

or, without reducing:

```
for e <- input do
  if e == :b, do: [:d, :b], else: e
end |> :lists.flatten()
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the question was: how do I insert an element between two specified elements--not how do I insert an element after a specified element.  If the `input` is `[:a, :b, :x]`, your code will insert the element `:d` after `:b`, yet the conditions for an insert will not have been met.

Comment: @DarckBlezzer Elixir has great documentation which is always faster to reach out compared to asking questions over the internets. https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1-the-reduce-option